# $location.search()["mode"] returns undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm relatively new to angularjs and have the following problem. I have a url that looks like:

```
localhost:10001/Broadcast/New?mode=launchQL&ID=U1DboHfQVU65VYQ21t5nLw
```

Inside my controller I'm trying to set some logic based on the parameters mode and ID.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter, $log, $timeout, $location){
$scope.mode = ($location.search())['mode'];
$scope.ID = ($location.search())['ID'];
}
```

I have not been able to determine why the $location.search() isn't returning the dictionary

```
{'mode':'launchQL', 'ID':'U1DboHfQVU65VYQ21t5nLw'}
```

as expected like the documentation says. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the things you use in AngularJS need to be behind an hash(#) or hashbang (#!). The url you have now is just a regular url with a regular querystring. What you want is a routing setup in your Single Page Application (SPA) in AngularJS that points to some controller. From there you can access the search variables if provides behind the normal route.

So your url should look like:

```
localhost:10001/Broadcast/New#someroute?mode=launchQL&ID=U1DboHfQVU65VYQ21t5nLw
```