# Not able to find query string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find query string value for string
   www.example.com/product?id=23

I am following this code

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('test', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
alert($location.search()['id']);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div app="myApp" controller="test">
</div>
```

Here is an example i want to get id value 23 as result.

How to do this>

following [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNX06WFx0n6p1mSLPKfP?p=preview)

Comment: var url = $location.absUrl().split('?')[0]

Comment: @SachinAghera Wouldn't we want the _second_ string returned from the split?

Comment: can you pls show me in url what you get?

Comment: How and where you are using this www.example.com/product?id=23 in your code ?

Comment: $location.absUrl().split('?')[0] is showing  `www.example.com/product`

Comment: @SudhirOjha while clicking on link a new address bar url is this

Comment: Have you tried this alert( $location.search().id);

Comment: undefined as below answer shows

Comment: your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964444/getting-values-from-query-string-in-an-url-using-angularjs-location?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957950/location-searchmode-returns-undefined-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get the query parameter

```
$location.search().id
```

returns an object, consisting of the keys as variables and the values as its value

```
myApp.controller('test', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function ($scope, $location, $http) {
alert( $location.search().id);
}]);
```

hey please check this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/eVQmw0asqu96hMxaPRvL?p=preview)

Comment: result is undefined

Comment: for me result is undefined

Comment: have you checked the link ? and are you getting any error ?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly should replace app and controller by `ng-app` and `ng-controller`
and `$location.search().id`